# p4 annotate a certain line from vim

Tags: bash, vim, perforce

I am trying to create a vim command in my `.vimrc` that will (probably) use `p4 annotate` to get the relevant changelist and its details for the current line I'm editing.

Tried to write something myself, but my bash/vim scripting skills aren't that great, and I couldn't find a way to get the changelist number of the current line.

How should such a vim command look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:
`command! Annotate execute '!p4 annotate -cq "%" | sed "' . line(".") . 'q;d" | cut -f1 -d: | xargs p4 describe -s | sed -e ''/Affected files/,$d'''`

I wrote something similar in **[this script](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-annotate)** that I currently use.
It's a version of p4 annotate that takes a file and a line as arguments and pretty prints them (and description-referenced changelists).
Note that the script depends on other scripts in the [repo](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u).
Btw, the [repo](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u)'s readme contains an example of a relevant vim command.